MOSFET or relay for controlling a PC fan?
I have a 12V DC 0.4A brushless PC fan. For my application, I'm going to drive it at a low speed with 5V DC (I tested and it did spin). I want to control it with a 5V logic signal (simply on and off, no PWM). I do have a couple of logic level mechanical relays. But I also have some 2N7000s laying around. I thought a relay was a little clunky and cumbersome, and wondered if a mosfet would work.

I understand that 2N7000 can be driven at 5V. But its resistance is somewhere around 5 Ohm. Is that too big for a DC motor like this?

More importantly, is the starting current of the motor going to kill the mosfet?


Thanks!

How much your fan draws at 5V and how much is the starting inrush current? And how much is current draw if you have 5 ohms in series?

Yeah, that's the question. What is a good way to measure the inrush current with a multimeter? Or is there a good way to estimate based on the running current?

3x running current is a good rule of thumb for starting current.

Thanks! Good to know! Lemme do some measurements.

Could parallel two FETs if you have them lying around to reduce the odds that you get the worst case 5 ohm resistance.

OK, I put a 5.6 ohm resistor in series, which is similar to 2N7000 when fully open, and measured 65 mA. If we go by 3x, that’s pushing the the current rating of 2N7000, 200 mA. But I guess it’s be fine for a short period of time?

Huh! Putting 2 in parallel is an interesting idea. Let me give it a try.

Update: I measured the running current and it was a little over 60 mA. Going with the assumption that the start current is 3x the running current, it's pushing the limit of 200 mA. So I did end up with putting 2 MOSFETs in parallel and it worked great.
Thanks for the suggestions and information.
